# How do I adjust Part 8 of The Traveller Campaign for more powerful characters?

Tags: published-adventures, encounter-design, traveller

I've just gotten to Adventure 8 in *The Traveller Campaign* and I have a problem: the characters are far too powerful for the adventure.

The main problem is that The Privateer Fleet that the characters command is too strong for Teirlas, his ships, his named followers and his available forces. The ships  that pursue them after they threaten Lokhart are a joke compared to my characters' fleet and, due to the skills, weapons, armour, gear and explosives the characters have access to, none of the listed Clan Forces have much of a chance.

**How can I adjust the adventure?** What should I add/change about the skills, stats, and equipment available to Teirlas, The Clan Agents, The Aslan Ships, and the troops that pursue them after they have threatened Lokhart, so that the adventure isn't a cakewalk?

*(I have been asked to pose this question by a friend who is running the campaign and does not have the internet.)*

---

Specific details of the PCs:

- Ships:

  - 3× 200-ton Drinax Harriers they get during the game
  - 2× 400-ton Gazelle Escorts captured during adventure 6
  - 2× 100-ton Aslan Scoutships captured during adventure 3
  - 1× custom-built 3,000-ton Frigate that they got after giving The Imperium the atomic and plague warheads from adventure 5 and faking the rescue of The Duke's niece in adventure 6
  - the 1,600-ton Treasure Ship from adventure 2
  - 1× 700-ton custom build raider that is based on how The PCs imagine a 700-ton Drinax Harrier would look

  Due to them investing 85% of their money in land, property and businesses that are based on ones off of telly, they earn enough to pay the monthly ship costs, pay the occassional repair bill and still net at least Cr £11,770 per month.

  All of the characters ships are crewed by slaves purchased from The Glorious Empire who have been genetically modified to be stronger, tougher, more attractive and more agile than normal, show unquestionable allegiance to their owner, have no mental capacity for treachery, but have enough intellect to go to the captain if he/she thinks one of the other PCs or a trusted advisor is a traitor. They never get paid, but, despite being slaves, are treated better than many of Tobia's poor, have a +3 DM to their key skills, a +2 DM to their 1 to 3 key skills and, despite their genetic modifications, have done some surprising things.
- The characters consist of

  - 2 marines/gunners
  - 1 pilot/navigator
  - 1 engineer/mechanic
  - 1 medic
  - 1 noble/captain

  All have have their key skills at between /3 and /5, 2 to 4 none key skills at /0 to /2 and stat DM's ranging from +0 to +3.
- Further PC details and advantages:

  - All have served between 5 and 8 terms
  - The 4 non-navy PCs all reached either rank 5 or rank 6
  - Both navy PCs reached rank 4 officer/rank 4 NCO
  - they all used Anagathics from terms 4 onwards

    - The Critic PC paid off their Anagthics debts, pays for monthly doses from his portfolio
  - The two PCs who are not marines all spent 10 months using a mixture of A Drinax Training Machine and partial training by the 2 marines to get:

    - Gun Combat - Energy Rifles /1
    - Battle Dress /0
    - Explosives /0
    - Heavy Weapons /0
  - while the 2 marines both have

    - Battle Dress /3
    - the other 3 skills (above) all at /3
- Equipment they all have access to:

  - 1× TL 14 FGMP
  - 1× suit of TL 14 Battle Dress
  - 3× TL 12 Laser Rifles
  - 3× TL 12 Mono Swords
  - 3× TL 15 Vacc Suits
  - 4 ½ months worth of food, drink, medicine and other survival gear
  - at least 17× each of Plasma, Frag and Incendiary Grenades
  - at least 270 pounds of TL 14 plastic explosive

Comment: Please clarify anything in the question that needs clarification, let's all lay off the huge comments.

Answer (score -1):

The slave crews are too uniform and unrealistically perfect without trade-offs.  Since it's likely too late to balance them properly, have some serious fault be revealed at a dramatic moment.

One good one is, allowing them to be frozen in place or knocked out by some form of sensory input.  Likely an anti-revolt safety feature secretly embedded by the supplier.

Of course this is covertly obtained/discovered by some enemy who foments a plot to exploit this weakness.

Answer (score -7):

The group has probably broken one or two laws, or at least can be framed.  In which case, arresting them would deprive them of everything they have.  Given their assets, keeping them in isolation might be justified.  Also, depending on the law they've broken, or been framed for breaking, it might be justification for either keeping the characters in isolation, or stripping them of everything.

You can then either decide to give everything back, if they're proven innocent after the fact, or whatever you want.

Comment: The questioner is asking how to adjust the campaign for this character force, not how to take their power away.  Taking everything away in a manner that seems arbitrary (as your suggestion surely would) is likely to damage or destroy the game group's cohesiveness.  Beyond that, it's unlikely there are forces in the sector capable of taking on the privateers, given they'd have been hired because the Imperium didn't have the power needed locally to begin with.